# kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host - GIT AND GITHUB

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am trying to push to a private git repo and am facing this error.

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 140.82.121.36 port 443
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried adding the block below to my .ssh/config file and it still doesn't work

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

I have also tried changing the internet connection to my mobile hotspot and it still wouldn't work.
Any solutions to this?

Comment: Did you install your ssh key on the server? This does not look like a connection issue, but rather like an authentication issue. When you try to access a private repo you don't have access to, GitHub will just tell you it doesn't exist.

Comment: @joanis Yes. I created and ssh key and added it to github. I created the key with `ssh-keygen -o` and copy the content of the `id_rsa.pub` and added it to github. I worked fine previously but all of the sudden it has started giving me this issues

Comment: Run `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to test the configuration with verbose output; observe the ssh conversation up to the point where the key exchange negotiation fails. This is an ssh issue, not a Git issue.